# scss seperate variables and mixins file (on heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sass

Many times I need to share css variables and mixins between files.  What I have done, is just move variables into a separate file named 'variables.css.scss' and then

```
 @import 'variables' to whatever sheets need 'em.
```

This works locally, because that separate file actually exists.  But, after compiling assets (like on heroku) that file is no where to be found...triggering load path error.

Is there a way of keeping variables and mixins DRY?

Comment: So Heroku is taking care of building the SCSS files? And you're sending all SCSS files to heroku (e.g. they're not in your `.gitignore`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@import is just like a partial.  For whatever reason my local environment is not being as strict as the heroku API is (strict is better).  All I needed to fix this was change the actual file name from 'variables.scss' to '_variables.scss'...just like a partial.  Heroku is happy now...